# mysql converting from UTC to IST

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a database storing records in UTC timestamp. I want to fetch them in terms of local time standard(IST).

By referring to some referral i tried like this.

```
select date(convert_tz(sa.created_at,'+00:00','+05:30')) as date,count(*) as hits from session_acts sa, sessions s where sa.session_id = s.id and s.created_at between convert_tz('2015-03-12T11:33:00+00:00','+00:00','-05:30') and convert_tz('2015-03-13T11:33:00+00:00','+00:00','-05:30') group by date;
```

But it will resulting in

```
+------------+------+
| date       | hits |
+------------+------+
| 2015-03-12 |   94 |
| 2015-03-13 |   34 |
+------------+------+
```

I want to display only hits that are requested on 13th. Where i am going wrong.?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IST is 5.30 hours ahead of UTC, so when 13th starts in IST i.e. `2015-03-13 : 00:00:00` its `2015-03-12 18:30:00` in UTC

```
mysql> select convert_tz('2015-03-13T00:00:00+00:00','+00:00','+05:30') ;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz('2015-03-13T00:00:00+00:00','+00:00','+05:30') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-03-12 18:30:00                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

And when 13 ends in IST i.e. `2015-03-13 : 23:59:59` its `2015-03-13 18:29:59` in UTC

```
mysql> select convert_tz('2015-03-13T23:59:59+00:00','+00:00','+05:30') ;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz('2015-03-13T23:59:59+00:00','+00:00','+05:30') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-03-13 18:29:59                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

So yo get the data in IST for 13th you will need to search data within this range of dates.

So the condition would be as below  -

```
s.created_at 
between convert_tz('2015-03-13T00:00:00+00:00','+00:00','+05:30')
and convert_tz('2015-03-13T23:59:59+00:00','+00:00','+05:30');
```

and since you are doing conversion at the time of select so it will return all 13th data.

Comment: i used 
`s.created_at 
between convert_tz('2015-03-13T00:00:00+00:00','+00:00','-05:30')
and convert_tz('2015-03-14T00:00+00:00','+00:00','-05:30');`

Comment: @h.APP.y good catch you can actually use `convert_tz('2015-03-14T00:00+00:00','+00:00','-05:30')` which you have done.

Comment: Thank you so much. I stuck with this issue last few days. You Saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert_tz('2015-03-13T00:00:00+00:00','+00:00','+05:30') ;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can lean from it

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Query - As per Indian Time zone

```
select CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+00:00','+12:30');
```

Output:

```
CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+00:00','+12:30')
2022-06-15 17:36:03
```