# Convert Timestamp to local time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timezone, datetime-conversion

I have a table in MySQL
Below is the structure of the table.. in that I have 2 column Date and Time and the timestamp is based on the country column.. I would like to convert this time into IST.. can any one help me how can we do this without a mapping table..

[image]

Comment: You can't do this without a lookup table.  You would need, at the very least, the MySQL timezone codes of each record, to know how to convert to a certain time zone.

Comment: Concat `Date`, `Time` and according zone as string literals, and use this expression like timestamp literal.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen.. Thanks you for the response.. OK.. can you help me with a link where I can get the timezone table for the world.. which I will maintain in my DB

Comment: Check the MySQL documentation for this.  Google "MySQL timezone".

Comment: YOU CAN REGER TO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163349/mysql-converting-from-utc-to-ist